# Remove "Reserved" password from PowerPoint 2013

Tags: ms-office, password-protection, powerpoint-2013

I have a PowerPoint file created in Microsoft Office 365 (2013), and we password protected it, the only thing is now I'm trying to remove it but it's still showing a password. It's showing 2 layers of password, if I set to encrypt it it shows that one, but then asks again for the "reserved" password. I can then remove the "encrypt" password but it still has a "reserved" password. Does anyone know how to remove the "reserved" password? I can't seem to find anything online.

Comment: Can someone move this question to Superuser please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go Save as (F12), then on the Save As Dialog, click Tools->General Options... next to the save button, and clear any passwords in there. :)